# AWS API Gateway Lambda regex not working/ Java

Tags: regex, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to match below regular expression for a specific response returned by Lambda function in java. But it does not seem to be working.

Lambda Error Regex -

```
.*"status:\s"422.*
```

Lambda error response format(response object is a POJO) -

```
{
  "id": "3sghsh3232",
  "status": 422,
  "responseCode": "INVALID-DATA",
  "message": "Please provide a valid data",
  "time": "2019-08-30T06:16:20.976",
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "422",
      "message": "Missing fields"
    }
  ]
}
```

Tried expressions -

```
".*\\\"status\\\":422.*"
.*422(.|\n)*
.*422.*
```

Comment: Why not parse the json itself?

Answer (score 1):

- I think this should work try it out at [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

```
\W*((?i)\"status\"(?-i))\:[\s]+422\,$   
or
\W*((?i)\"status\")\:\s+422\,$
or
\W*(\"status\")\:*\s422\,$
```

- `\W*` matches any non-word character (equal to [^a-zA-Z0-9_])
- `(?i)` match the remainder of the pattern with the following effective flags:gmi
- `\"` matches the character " literally (case insensitive)
- `\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
- `\,` matches the character , literally (case sensitive)

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you will see, your regex is incorrect:

```
.*"status:\s"422.*
         ^ (look here)
```

1. `.*` matches any string before what follows.
2. `"status:\ "` matches literally the sequence of double quotes, the word `status`, ... **beeep** (there's a double quote after status, not after the colon and the next space character).

---

## NOTE

Response object is not a POJO (pojo stands for the acronym (P)lain (O)ld (J)ava (O)bject, and what you are posting is, indeed, a JSON encoded string data)

---

The correct regexp should be (as the data shows):

```
"status":\s*(\d+),
       ^ (see how we moved the double quotes here)
```

1. The `.*` is not necessary, as any regexp that has no anchor char (`^` at the beginning, or `$` at the end) matches at any position in the string.
2. Then follows the string `"status":` literally.
3. Then a group `\s*` of spaces (indeed, tab or spaces, any number, even zero is valid)
4. Then a group of one or more digits (the parenthesis makes the subexpression to become a group, so you can select only the part matching that group, and get the status value)
5. Finally, the `,` comma after all, as everytime the status will be followed by a comma to separate the next field.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bNwjPY/1).

Comment: nice one, just a small amendment `"status":\s*422,` So that it only checks for 422 response not any number.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know... but include the comma, as not doing could include a number like `4223`.